# Sort MySQL select from another table data

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, sorting

I have 2 tables that involve this query.

```
Table : Discussions            Table : Comments
--------------------           -------------------------------------
|id | content      |           | id | d_id | content   | timestamp |
--------------------           -------------------------------------
| 1 | Text String  |           | 1  |  2   | Comment 1 | timestamp |
| 2 | Text String  |           | 2  |  3   | Comment 2 | timestamp |
| 3 | Text String  |           | 3  |  4   | Comment 3 | timestamp |
| 4 | Text String  |           | 4  |  2   | Comment 4 | timestamp |
| 5 | Text String  |           | 5  |  3   | Comment 5 | timestamp |
--------------------           -------------------------------------
```

Now I need to get the `id` from the `discussion` table, and I need to sort it using the `d_id` in the `comment` table according to a Unix timestamp in the comments table. If there is no comment then I need to sort discussions using timestamp in the discussions table. so newly posted discussions without any comments will added to the top of the page.

Comment: Add the expected result set to fully understand what you want exactly

Comment: I expect there is a `JOIN` and an `ORDER BY` clause in the query you tried, right?

Comment: yes ... there is INNER JOIN & ORDER BY :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to list just the `content` from `Discussions` ordered by `timestamp` from `Comments`, then you need to left join to include all discussions (including those without comments):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Discussions.id, Discussions.content
FROM Discussions
LEFT JOIN Comments ON Discussions.id = Comments.d_id
ORDER BY -Comments.timestamp DESC, Discussions.timestamp DESC
```

where I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174026/3704831) to make sure the `Discussions` with `null` for `timestamp`, that is, the discussions with no comments, come last.

Comment: I just need the id of the discussion ordered by timestamp from associated comments with that discussion. I also need the latest discussion if discussion don't have any comments.

Comment: @ShyaminAyesh: you changed the goal posts. It's completely unfair to ask a question and then comment that the answer doesn't do quite something you never specified. All query requirements need to be listed in your question.

Comment: I changed the question for better readability :D sorry for the issue & please take a look it now. :)

Comment: @ShyaminAyesh Your description of the `Discussions` table still doesn't include a timestamp field? Is one to assume that the order of the `id` implies  which is oldest?

Comment: @wogsland : assume that the order of `discussions.timestatmp` implies which is oldest.

Answer (score 0):

supposing that the connection between the two tables is

comments.d_id = Discussions.id

I would do it like this

```
select Discussions.*, comments.*
from Discussions 
left join comments
on comments.d_id = Discussions.id
order by comments.timestamp desc, comments.d_id
```

Comment: this will won't work if there is no comments associated with discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this in steps:

```
SELECT d.id,
       ( SELECT id FROM Comments
             WHERE discussion_id = d.id
             ORDER BY created_on DESC
             LIMIT 1 ) AS latest_comment_id
    FROM Discussions AS d
    WHERE d.is_active = 1
      AND d.is_pinned = 0
      AND d.is_sink = 0
    ORDER BY
        c.id IS NOT NULL,  -- to get non-commented discussions first
        d.timestamp  DESC, -- if you want latest first
    LIMIT 50;
```

And have

```
INDEX(discussion_id, created_on)
```

That should give you one row per discussion, with the comment-less discussions first (newest first), then those with comments (again, newest first).

Add more columns if you need more stuff from Discussions.

The second step would be get more info from Comments, if you desire.  But first, let me know what you need from it.  In particular, a `COUNT(*)` would be lead down a different path than fetching other columns.

Comment: This is nearly perfect. But this also returns the same `Discussions` row more than 1 time.

Comment: And which Comment should be returned if there are multiple ones?  If you want the "latest", then you are into the realm of [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Comment: yes. if there is multiple comments for single discussion I need the latest one :D